# Chamar ProgressBar de projeto winforms em projeto de testes na mesma solution

Tags: winforms, progress-bar, testes-automatizados

Amigos,
Estou com 2 projetos na mesma solution, 1 de destes codedUI e outro com winform contendo uma simples barra de progresso. Foi realizado a importação no projeto de testes da referencia e instanciado a mesma onde gostaria de chamar. O problema é que ao chamar o método que incrementa o valor da barra o mesmo não e exibido. Ou seja, a comunicação acontece mas a barra não é exibida.
Gostaria da contribuições para que chamada da barra seja exibida no momento em que o testes está sendo debugado.
Barra de progresso:

```
namespace ProgressBar Form1
{
    public partial class ProgressBar : Form
    {
        public ProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void progressBar1_Value()
        {

                progressBar1.Value += 10;

        }

        public void show()
        {

            progressBar1.Show();


        }


    }
}
```

Chamada da barra no teste:

```
using projeto = ProgressBar;
projeto.ProgressBar Barra = new projeto.ProgressBar();
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                Barra.progressBar1_Value();
                Barra.show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Fala pessoal,

Consegui identificar o que faltava no código. Estranhamente o "Barra.Show" só funcionou após limpar e rebuildar o projeto.
A solução limpar/Rebuildar a barra de progresso criada em um projeto winform. Mas a chamada é isso mesmo, o método show() quem faz a exibição da barra.